# CMS error in content area when Multi Languages

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I want to  translate my website to another language.The website build as content management system, the default language is work good but when press

```
<div id='languages'><a href="Template.php?lang=ar"><img src='Images/ar.png' /></a</div>
```

menu part is translate it but in content area I got an error 
undefined content in

```
<div id="content_area">
                    <?php 

                         echo $content ; 
                         ?>
```

Comment: Does your content have translations?  Where is $content being set, and what value should it have?

Comment: the value contain  forms method get and  post , tables and paragraph will be set in same page but in content area  above the content area there is menu that when click will change the content area

Comment: codes
template.php
http://pastebin.com/g4DzpMMU

here the error in templateAr.php
http://pastebin.com/0NjwbR1v

index.php
http://pastebin.com/0878S307

indexAr.php
http://pastebin.com/uVM0TqmG